# await is only valid in async function within multiple for loops

Tags: node.js, mongodb, for-loop, asynchronous, async-await

```
async function myfunc(fruits) {
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        fruits.forEach(fruitId => {
            colors = await dbHelper.getColor(fruitId);
            colors.forEach(color => {
                taste = await dbHelper.gettaste(color);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

How do we get this to work,with multiple for loops.The dbhelper functions are fetching some data from the database.

Comment: Instead of `forEach`, Use `for..of` loop,

Answer (score 0):

Your code have a several mistakes (check out below) and should look like this:

```js
async function myfunc(fruits) {
    try { 
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (let fruitId of fruits) {
                colors = await dbHelper.getColor(fruitId);
                for (let color of colors) {
                    taste = await dbHelper.gettaste(color);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(err) {
        // Handle somehow
    }
}
```

**Why?**

1. You call async methods from `dbHelper` inside of `forEach` arrow function instead of `myfunc` directly, so `await` keyword will not allowed there, you should add `async` keyword to methods where async methods calls.
2. Awaiting **will not works** there because `forEach` loop can't pause code execution. Solution: change `forEach` loops to `for (... in/of ...)`.
3. You didn't handle errors anywhere. Keep in mind that any async method can be rejected, so you need to be ready for it and handle errors somehow. Solution: add `try/catch`.

Also you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop?rq=1) about asyncing during loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to retrieve an array of taste you can do something like this

```
async function myfunc(fruits) {
   const colors = await Promise.all(fruits.map(fruitId =>dbHelper.getColor(fruitId)));
   const tastes = await Promise.all(colors.map(color => dbHelper.gettaste(color)));
   ...
}
```

or shorter

```
async function myfunc(fruits) {
   const colors = await Promise.all(fruits.map(dbHelper.getColor));
   const tastes = await Promise.all(colors.map(dbHelper.gettaste));
   ...
}
```